# Access the channel from a http.Request instance in Twisted

Tags: python, twisted, twisted.web

I'm working on a project that uses the Twisted `web` facilities, but not the high-level web framework. How can I get access to the `HTTPChannel` instance (the twisted `protocol`) that created a certain `http.Request` instance?

I see that the constructor of `http.Request` has the channel as an argument, but there is not method/property that further accesses it.

Also, while I can access the `HTTPFactory` instance from the channel via the `factory` property - can i access the factory directly from the request instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the channel is available directly on the `Request`.  Consider `Request.__init__`:

```
def __init__(self, channel, queued):
    """                                                                                                                                     
    @param channel: the channel we're connected to.                                                                                         
    @param queued: are we in the request queue, or can we start writing to                                                                  
        the transport?                                                                                                                      
    """
    self.notifications = []
    self.channel = channel
    self.queued = queued
    ...
```

`self.channel = channel` seems to be just what you're looking for.

Comment: Yes, this is like the wrapper class i'm using. But maybe there's a reason why it's not accessible right away?

Comment: I don't understand this comment.  That's `twisted.web.http.Request.__init__`, not a wrapper class.  It has a `channel` attribute right on it.  I don't know what "not accessible right away" means.

Comment: Well, with re-implementing a constructor you are creating a wrapper for the request to be used instead of the original implementation. "not accessible right away" - this means that with the original implementation of the request you can't access the channel with an instance.

Comment: That is *the* constructor.  That is not a re-implementation of the constructor.  I copy/pasted from the source code.

Comment: Yes. You are correct. My problem appeared when I try to access the `channel` from `request` _outside_ the `process` method. I'm accepting this answer and I'll post another question soon explaining what exactly is happening. Thank you for your patience.